# R: Replacing empty string with "0" in data frame column results in all column values being replaced with "0"

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a R dataframe called `newdata` which I have read in using `read.csv()`:

```
PROPDMGEXP   EVTYPE

"K"          WIND
"M"          HAIL
"H"          TORNADO
"B"          WIND
"+"          HIGH WIND
"-"          TORNADO
"?"          HURRICANE
             WIND
             TORNADO
"k"          HAIL
```

The blank values in the `PROPDMGEXP` column were blank cells in the CSV file from which the data was read. I am assuming that they are empty strings.
I want to replace the values in the `PROPDMGEXP` column with other values, and I have used regex to do so:

```
newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("K", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "10^3"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("H", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "10^2"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("M", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "10^6"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("B", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "10^9"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("+", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, fixed = TRUE)] <- "1"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("-", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, fixed = TRUE)] <- "0"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("?", newdata$PROPDMGEXP, fixed = TRUE)] <- "0"

newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("", newdata$PROPDMGEXP)] <- "0"
```

I have checked whether the values are being replaced through subsetting the data and printing it out:

```
mydata <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "10^6", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata1 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "10^3", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata2 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "10^2", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata3 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "10^9", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata4 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "1", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata5 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "0", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata7 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "-", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata8 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "?", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

mydata9 <- subset(newdata, PROPDMGEXP == "", select=c(EVTYPE, PROPDMGEXP))

print(head(mydata))

print(head(mydata1))

print(head(mydata2))

print(head(mydata3))

print(head(mydata4))

print("Printing 0...")
print(head(mydata5))
   
print("Printing -")
print(head(mydata7))

print("Printing ?")
print(head(mydata8))

print("Printing blank")
print(head(mydata9))
```

I have found that when I replace the empty string values in the `PROPDMGEXP` column with "0", this results in all the other replaced values that are not "0" (e.g. "10^3", "10^2", "10^6", etc) in the `PROPDMGEXP` column being replaced with "0".

I have verified this through the following:

```
print(dim(newdata))
> 902297      7

print(length(which(newdata$PROPDMGEXP == "0")))
> 902297
```

I am not sure why this is occurring. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `read.csv("yourfile.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings=c("","0"))` to read in your data, then remove `newdata$PROPDMGEXP[grepl("", newdata$PROPDMGEXP)] <- "0"` from your code? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Thanks, I tried read.csv("yourfile.csv", header=TRUE, na.strings=c("")) and it worked for me.

Comment: `grepl("", x)` is `TRUE` for all `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `grepl("", newdata$PROPDMGEXP)` is all `TRUE`. If you ever need to use this kind of approach again, better use

```
newdata$PROPDMGEXP[newdata$PROPDMGEXP==""] <- "0"
```

especially if you are doing complete matching and/or you know exactly the string you're going to replace; or if it's empty. Because it will match only empty strings instead of match with everything.